# d3 enter not placing data

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, svg

Using d3, I am reading in 8760 data points (one for each hour of 2013) from a csv into a 2-d array and then trying to create them as circles in an `<svg>` element.  The code successfully imports the data, as I can view it in the browser's console.  However, the enter function does not seem to be applying the data to create the circles.  No errors are raised.

Code:

```
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var w = 900, h = 500;
  var dataset = [];

  d3.csv("Jsorted2.csv", function(error, data) {
    dataset = data.map(function(d) { return [ +d["Load"], new Date(d["dtDateTime"]), +d["Month"], +d["Hour"], +d["DayofYear"], +d["NetLoad"]]; });
  });

  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

  svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data( dataset )
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return i; })
    .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return d[0]; })
    .attr("r", function(d,i) { return d[5]; });

</script>
```

The data loads properly:

[Browser Inspector Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap0ts.png)

But the circles are missing:

[Browser Inspector Source Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS09h.png)

I have found different errors if I change the initial definition of dataset.  If I use

```
var dataset = [[]];
```

the data still loads, but now I receive an error when d3 tries the grab the data:

```
d3.v4.min.js:3 Error: <circle> attribute cy: Expected length, "NaN".
(anonymous function) 
@ d3.v4.min.js:3Q_ 
@ d3.v4.min.js:6K_ 
@ d3.v4.min.js:6(anonymous function) 
@ D3test4LD.html:29
```

And d3 gets a little further in creating the circles:

```
<svg width="900" height="500">
<circle cx="0" cy="NaN"></circle>
</svg>
```

Why does d3 not load the data to circles?  It appears as if d3 is not passing the data to d as it should, as d[0] has no length.  If I cannot get this to work, I'll just write a Javascript for loop to place them myself, but I'd like to figure out why this doesn't work.  It looks like a type conversion issue, but I import the data with a +, which is supposed to set the data as a number.  I can even test that in the console:

```
> typeof(dataset[0][0])
"number"
```

Please do not include a js for loop as a solution.

---

### UPDATE

So, I did solve my problem after researching asynchronous data loading, as per the answer below.  For clear and easy future reference, here is one way to code a solution:

```
setInterval(drawLD, 2000);

function drawLD(){
    svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data( dataset )
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return Math.round(i/8760); })
      .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return Math.round(d[0]/maxload); })
      .attr("r", function(d,i) { return 2; });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`d3.csv` is an asynchronous function. The code that creates the circles is executed before your csv data has returned. Place your d3 code inside the callback.

```
<script>
  var w = 900, h = 500;
  var dataset = [];

  d3.csv("Jsorted2.csv", function(error, data) {
    dataset = data.map(function(d) { return [ +d["Load"], new Date(d["dtDateTime"]), +d["Month"], +d["Hour"], +d["DayofYear"], +d["NetLoad"]]; });

    var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

  svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data( dataset )
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return i; })
    .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return d[0]; })
    .attr("r", function(d,i) { return d[5]; });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So more like this? http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/5113469  Do you suggest I use SetInterval? Or possibly an update button that triggers the circle drawing?

Comment: No, do not use setInterval to "guess" when your csv data is loaded. My answer is the standard javascript way to execute code when you are SURE the data is loaded. The call back function is only called when the data has either loaded or failed.